# How to prove that $\aleph{(T)} \subseteq \aleph{(T^{n})}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

How can I show that if we apply the operator $T$ , $n$ times on a vector (where $n$ is a natural number), the null space of $T$ will be a subset of the resulting null space of $T^n$ ?

I've already found out that $T$ should be linear otherwise this statement would not be true.

I guess I should choose a random vector belonging to $\aleph{(T)} = \{x|T(x) = 0\}$ and then show that this vector would be in $\aleph{(T^n)}$ but I don't know how to write this procedure succinctly?

Comment: Yo need only a small consequence of linearity, namely that $T(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, null $T=\{v\in V:Tv=0\}$. Now, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $v \in$ null $T$, we have: $$T^kv=T^{k-1}(Tv)=T^{k-1}(0)=0.$$
Hence, $v \in$ null $T^k$.

Answer (score 1):

The null space of $T$ is exactly "the stuff $T$ maps to zero."

Now, suppose $x$ is in the null space of $T$. Then $T(x)=0$. What do you know about $T(0)$? What does this tell you about $T^2(x), T^3(x), . . . $?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to know that $ \forall k\in \mathbb{N},\;\; N(T^{k})\subseteq N(T^{k+1}) $ which its proof is simple. And also the other similar useful relation in linear algebra is as follow
$$ \forall k\in \mathbb{N},\;\; R(T^{k+1})\subseteq R(T^{k}). $$